# How to use ID or CLASS instead of using name in Bootstrap Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is to validated field(s) that has a class name or Id using the bootstrap validator

Here is the example code :

HTML:

```
<input id="myFirstId" class="myClass" type="text" name="myFirstName" />
<input id="mySecondId" class="myClass" type="text" name="myLastName" />
```

JS:

```
 $('#myForm').bootstrapValidator({

        fields : {
            myFirstName : {      
                validators : {
                    notEmpty : {
                        message : 'required'
                    }
                }
            },
            myLastName : {
                validators : {
                    notEmpty : {
                        message : 'required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 });
```

but i want a single block to validated those two element using bootstrap validator

ex.

```
$('#myForm').bootstrapValidator({

        fields : {
            myClass : {      // <-- this is not working but i want to validate those
                             // object with has 'myClass' class.
                validators : {
                    notEmpty : {
                        message : 'required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See http://bootstrapvalidator.com/settings/#field-selector

You can use `selector` instead of name to use a class name:

```
$('#myForm').bootstrapValidator({
    fields: {
        myClass: {
            selector: '.myClass',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'required'
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: As per checking the link you gave, it still need the name of the selector. "fields: {
            selectorName: {
                selector: '#ccNumber',... "

Comment: That's why I have `myClass : { selector: ".myClass" ...`

Comment: I red some comment in gihub and i found this. and it confirms your answer to be correct. $('#form').bootstrapValidator({
    <inputName>: {
        selector: ...,  // Can be null (default), '#id' or '.class'
    }
}); here is the link . https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/issues/56

Comment: your answer to my question is correct. but I am still making and looking some solution. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Werd No worries. Why aren't you happy with this solution out of curiosity?